# Is there a way to unpack a password protected archive?

Tags: passwords, archiving

There's an archive (.ize, IZArc file) I made a few years ago, with a password. Now I need to open it, but I forgot the password. Is there any way to recover the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without the password, or a password cracking program.

Comment: Are there any? This is very important and I must extract the file that's in it before sunday.

Comment: All I can suggest to do is use Google to search for one, they are application specific, so if it is zip file, Google search for "password recovery winzip" If the password is over 6 characters it could take a very long time to crack it, if it is 7 or more, its not worth trying unless it is a dictionary type common password.